# Returning a Variable from a Separate Method, but I still get errors

Tags: java, methods, return, symbols

Hello stackoverflow community. Currently I'm new to java and I'm trying to figure out how to module program. For whatever reason when I return the variable averageScore, it gives me an error for that variable in the main method. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Program4
{

public static void main(String[  ] args)
{
    EasyReader console = new EasyReader(); //Connect to EasyReader.class
    System.out.print("Enter the score from game 1: ");
    double score1 = console.readDouble(); //Reads the user input for game 1 
    System.out.print("Enter the score from game 2: ");
    double score2 = console.readDouble(); //Reads the user input for game 2
    System.out.print("Enter the score from game 3: ");
    double score3 = console.readDouble(); //Reads the user input for game 3
    average(score1, score2, score3);
    displayScores(score1, score2, score3, averageScore);
}
public static void average(double score1, double score2, double score3)
{
    double averageScore = ((double)score1+score2+score3)/3; //Divides miles by gallons  
    getAverage();
}
public static double getAverage()
{
    return new averageScore;
}   
public static void displayScores(double score1, double score2, double score3, double averageScore)
{
    System.out.println("Game 1 Score: " + score1 + " points"); //Prints score 1
    System.out.println("Game 2 Score: " + score2 + " points"); //Prints score 2
    System.out.println("Game 3 Score: " + score3 + " points"); //Prints score 3     
    System.out.println("Average score: " + RoundDouble.roundDouble(averageScore, 2) + " points "); //Prints the average score and rounds it to 2 decimals
}
}
```

Comment: Consider scope and check the methods that return values.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, could you clarify?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you simply call `getAverage();`?

Comment: Its goods good practice to include the relevant parts of your stack trace along with your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static double average(double score1, double score2, double score3)
{
    return ((double)score1+score2+score3)/3; //Divides miles by gallons  
}
```

then in your main method, you can do something like this:

```
EasyReader console = new EasyReader(); //Connect to EasyReader.class
System.out.print("Enter the score from game 1: ");
double score1 = console.readDouble(); //Reads the user input for game 1 
System.out.print("Enter the score from game 2: ");
double score2 = console.readDouble(); //Reads the user input for game 2
System.out.print("Enter the score from game 3: ");
double score3 = console.readDouble(); //Reads the user input for game 3
double averageScore = average(score1, score2, score3);
displayScores(score1, score2, score3, averageScore);
```

You don't need the getAverage() method anymore

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `score1`, `score2`, `score3`, `averageScores` are all local inside the method.
Declare them as `attributes` of the `class Program4` and then access them by `instantiating` an object of `Class Program4`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems here:

`average(score1, score2, score3);`

You haven't assigned the return value to anything locally accessible. Assign the value of `average()` to a local variable, just like you did with score3, for example.

```
public static void average(double score1, double score2, double score3)
{
    double averageScore = ((double)score1+score2+score3)/3; //Divides miles by gallons  
    getAverage();
}
```

What? Just return `averageScore` from here, no need to invoke another method to do it.